# Is there a way to transfer my question to a different site?

Tags: support

I'd like to have my question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731599/how-can-i-add-a-column-to-multiple-tables-at-once-in-mysql-workbench transferred to for example https://dba.stackexchange.com/?as=1 instead of it just vanishing into nirvana because it has been closed and apparently is somehow "off-topic" where it is. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Flag it for moderator attention and ask for it to be considered for migration. Us the "other" option to do so. Note that I have no idea if it's a good fit, so that request might be rejected.

Comment: OK, but then I'm wondering whether it does fit anywhere if not there. On the other hand, I think it's a valid question with a valid answer and it could be useful to a lot of people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can - depending on your rep - vote to close as "off-topic, belongs on DBA" or flag the message and mention that it should be migrated to DBA.

However, your question on its own fits more to Stack Overflow in my opinion since it's very RoR-specific and not so much DB-specific. However, after reading the comment about your client being not-so-intelligent and using some external too to manage the DB structure I guess [dba.se] would be a better fit indeed. But please consider rewording the question first to clarify that you cannot use RoR migrations to do it.

==> Migrated it to DBA

Comment: OK, I'll edit the question. Thanks for an actually useful answer, rather than just closing the question as "off-topic" and leaving me to figure out why it is not appropriate the way it is.

Comment: @nerdinand if you ever wonder why it was closed, you're welcome to ask on Meta. As long as you're constructively trying to figure out why it happened, users here are often more than willing to explain it to you.